# Automatic features provision on Fuse ESB/Servicemix with Maven

Tags: maven, osgi, fuseesb, jbossfuse, autodeploy

Is there any way to provision/deploy features to Fuse ESB/Servicemix automaticaly though Maven, like cargo for Tomcat? Using ant+ssh is not an option.

Comment: Tried http://mvnplugins.fusesource.org/maven/1.14-SNAPSHOT/maven-provision-plugin/index.html ?

Comment: What are you trying to do? Is this to do automatic tests?

Comment: This is needed for automatic deployment on Fuse. I was thinking about something like JMX based, that i could see if bundles are actually provisioned and fail build if they are not, so Maven Provision Plugin doesn't look usable. Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

I'm currently finalizing a client wrapped in a maven plugin that will do just that, but instead of the fusesource approach of using the hot deployment folder I connect directly to the remote karaf console and execute the commands required to (un)install features.

The auto deploy is part of automated regression tests executed by Jenkins through a set of SoapUI test scripts.

Basically I use apache SSHD to connect to karaf (see an example here: https://cwiki.apache.org/KARAF/63-programmatically-connect-to-the-console.html) and some custom code to execute the commands and parse the result.

Comment: Your link is not active any longer.  Is this available somewhere else?